# Efficient way to forward-fill nulls in time-series data using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with time-series data that's mostly nulls, and I want to fill in all of the nulls with the last known value.

I have a few solutions, but they're much slower than doing the equivalent `DataFrame.fillna(method='ffill')` operation in Pandas.

A simplified version of the code / data that I'm using:

```
select d.[date], d.[price],
       (select top 1 p.price from price_table p
        where p.price is not null and p.[date] <= p.[date]
        order by p.[date] desc) as ff_price
from price_table d
```

To produce the table

```
date       price ff_price
---------- ----- --------
2016-07-11 0.79  0.79
2016-07-12 NULL  0.79
2016-07-13 NULL  0.79
2016-07-14 0.69  0.69
2016-07-15 NULL  0.69
...
2016-09-21 0.88  0.88
...
```

I have >100 million rows, so this takes quite a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your column is `DATE` and price is `DECIMAL(5,2)`, please test this approach:

```
SELECT
    P.[date],
    P.[price],
    ff_price = CONVERT(
        DECIMAL(5,2),       -- Original price datatype
        SUBSTRING(
            MAX(
                CAST(P.[date] AS BINARY(3)) +   -- 3: datalength of P.[date] column
                CAST(P.[price] AS BINARY(5))    -- 5: datalength of P.[price] column
            ) OVER (ORDER BY P.[date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),

            4,  -- Position to start that's not the binary part of the date

            5))-- Characters that compose the binary of the original price datatype
FROM
    price_table  AS P
```

This is a solution I implemented with a similar problem and you can find the exaustive explanation [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle). The reason this approach is good is because ***it doesn't require a explicit sort***, as long as you have an index by `date`.

What it does is basically use a windowed `MAX` with the concatenation of the 3 bytes that composes your date column (this is why I mentioned that you column must be `DATE`, otherwise `DATETIME` will need 8 bytes, you can edit the query to work with this) with the bytes that compose your price column (which are 5 bytes, also assumed). This is the `CAST(P.[date] AS BINARY(3)) + CAST(P.[price] AS BINARY(5))` part.

When you calculate this and `ORDER BY P.[date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, the engine is basically doing rolling max with values which most significant bytes are your dates. The max result will always update when the date changes, but considering that concatenating any value with `NULL` as price will also yield `NULL` (as binary), then the `MAX` will always ignore this value and retain the previous non-null `MAX` (by `P.[date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`).

This is the binary result of the windowed `MAX` (I added a previous record with `NULL` so you see that result is `NULL` for null prices values):

```
date        price   ff_price    WindowedMax
2016-07-10  NULL    NULL        NULL
2016-07-11  0.79    0.79        0x9B3B0B050200014F
2016-07-12  NULL    0.79        0x9B3B0B050200014F
2016-07-13  NULL    0.79        0x9B3B0B050200014F
2016-07-14  0.69    0.69        0x9E3B0B0502000145
2016-07-15  NULL    0.69        0x9E3B0B0502000145
2016-07-21  0.88    0.88        0xA53B0B0502000158
2016-07-22  NULL    0.88        0xA53B0B0502000158
```

Comment: This solution required a lot of fiddling to get working, but the mechanics make quite a bit of sense to me. It actually performs comparably to @Larnu s solution (23 seconds), much better than my original one or the APPLY approach.

Comment: @user448830 yes it's a bit more "under the hood" solution, but when dealing with big datasets or performance, learning these tricks is really helpful. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a "classic" gaps and island question. *Assuming* you're not using 2008 or prior (which are all (almost) entirely out of support) this *should* get you the result you're after:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [date],
           price,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN price IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [date]
                                                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM price_table p)
SELECT [date],
       price,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS ff_price
FROM CTE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f4a3801e7e4db9f66d6fd54cd43b02d)

Comment: This was by far faster than the other solutions: running against 135 million rows it finished in <21 seconds, compared to >330 for all of the other answers.

It was also the most difficult to wrap my brain around, but now that I've figured out why it works it seems really clever.

Comment: Glad you figured it our @user448830. the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause is a great addition to the window functions that was added in SQL Server 2012. If you understand the syntax, hopefully you can put it to good use in the future. :)

Comment: what is the purpose of the `rows between unbounded preceding ...` part? I was trying to do something similar and it works for me without that part as well. Just ordering by date is enough for me.

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default window @gouravkr, I just prefer to define it; just in case that ever changes.

Comment: I had a similar solution where I would define the grouping variable in one subquery and then take a cumulative sum of it outside. This solution achieved the same with one fewer level of subquery. Interesting how many ways there are to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.*, t1.price AS ff_price
FROM price_table t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t1.*
      FROM price_table t1
      WHERE t1.[date] <= t.[date] AND t1.price IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY t1.[date] DESC
     ) t1;
```