# How to assign the most recent paid campaign to subsequent visits in SQl?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below with the first five columns. I need to build the sixth column. I'm not sure how to go about this. I need to assign the most recent Paid Campaign a customer came through to subsequent visits.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If not, what research have you done to try solve this, and what didn't you understand in the articles/documentation you read? We can then help explain it. Also, please don't post images of data. Data is text, and (as a minimum) should be posted as formatted `text`.

Comment: Also looks like duplicate of [Efficient way to forward-fill nulls in time-series data using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889595/efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nulls-in-time-series-data-using-t-sql)

Comment: @Larnu, that link was super helpful, thanks :)

Comment: @Larnu, Sorry about the image! Will post as formatted text going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.*, t1.campaign AS MostRecentPaidCampaigns 
FROM table t OUTER APPLY 
     (SELECT TOP (1) t1.*
      FROM TABLE t1
      WHERE t1.CookieID = t.CookieID AND t1.session_id < t.session_id AND t1.campaign IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY t1.DATE DESC
     ) t1;
```